# As3: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor (BitmapData)

Tags: actionscript-3, class, constructor, flash-cs5, instantiation

I'm so sorry if this question has been answered before or the answer is painfully obvious, but I could really use some help.

So I have this Class I want to create instances off of. The idea is to give each instance a unique Bitmap for later usage, but I've run into some problems.

The code in my timeline looks like this:

```
var en3:Chime_enemy = new Chime_enemy();
en3.icon_ = thundertest; //an image in my library
```

And here is the code in my Class. I'll post two functional options without the desired result: (1)

```
public class Chime_battler extends MovieClip
{
    public var bit:Bitmap;
    public var b:BitmapData;
    public var icon_:Class;

    public function Chime_battler()
    {
        bit = new Bitmap;
        b = new thundertest(30,30); //Should use icon_
        bit.bitmapData = b;
    }
}
```

However this also worked (IIRC), but seeing as I had to use addChild it was not a desired option: (2)

```
public class Chime_battler extends MovieClip
{
    public var bit:Bitmap;
    public var b:BitmapData;
    public var icon_:Class;

    public function Chime_battler()
    {
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
    }

    private function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void
    {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);

        bit = new Bitmap;
        b = new icon_;
        bit.bitmapData = b;
    }
```

I basically want to use (2), but placed in the constructor function as (1) is.

Here's how I will use it later on (in the timeline):

```
var img:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
img = en3.bit;
addChild(img);
```

I'm sorry if this makes no sense whatsoever. I'd appreciate any help possible.

Comment: I realize I can just create a symbol out of thundertest for so much more easier handling, but since I haven't planned to use it for anything remotely needing a MovieClip it seems like a waste.

Comment: You only need to listen for `Added_to_stage` when you're doing something that is dependent on the `stage` object or the `parent` of a display object.  Doesn't look like you're using either so it shouldn't produce any different results than having it in the construtor.

Comment: Chime_enemy extends Chime_battler. It contains almost nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
public class Chime_battler extends MovieClip {
    public var icon:Bitmap = new Bitmap;
    public function Chime_battler(iconBmd:BitmapData) {
        icon.bitmapData = iconBmd;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
var en3:Chime_Battler = new Chime_battler(new thundertest);
addChild(en1.icon);
```

This way you can also save a bit of memory using the same bitmapdata for all instances (if you don't plan on modifying it in each instance):

```
var thunderIcon:BitmapData = new thundertest;
...
var en1:Chime_Battler = new Chime_battler(thunderIcon);
var en2:Chime_Battler = new Chime_battler(thunderIcon);
...
addChild(en1.icon);
addChild(en2.icon);
```

However, if you really need to pass the class name and create the instance inside your constructor (it's a bit ugly, but sometimes it's needed) your constructor would be like this:

```
public class Chime_battler extends MovieClip {
    public var icon:Bitmap = new Bitmap;
    public function Chime_battler(IconClass:Class) {
        icon.bitmapData = new IconClass;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
var en3:Chime_Battler = new Chime_battler(thundertest);
addChild(en1.icon);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!
The middle version worked perfectly, but I would much rather use the bottom solution, though I'm not really sure how to. When I try it I simply get the same error I did before. I want to try to avoid using variables outside the class itself and create the instance within the constructor.

Comment: Silly me, forgot the _= new Bitmap;_ after _icon:Bitmap_.
Works great, thanks a million!